# How to enforce / limit one device per user

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

From the following thread my comprehension of WSO2 EMM is it allows multiple devices per user.
[WSO2 EMM: Delete device from Device Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412314/wso2-emm-delete-device-from-device-management).

1. Is true that once registered is impossible to remove. only manually delete from EMM ?
2. Is there a way to enforce / limit one device per user (in both scenario: **BYOD** & **COPE**)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Wipe or Enterprise Wipe to remove a device form a user. 
   (Wipe will remove all the data which is in the device and remove the device from EMM. Enterprise Wipe will remove only the enterprise data and remove the device from EMM)
2. Currently you cannot. But you can customize EMM for that purpose since WSO2 EMM is free and opensource.

Comment: Thanks Chatura, After waiting few days for an answer I was tinking no one could answer my question